# how to find this with regex

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Hi

How can I find emails with regex ?

```
"sdafsad@asdfsa.com"
"sdaf-sad@asdfsa.com"
"sdaf-sad@asdfsa.com"
"sdaf-sad@asdf-sa.com"
"sdaf_sad@asdf-sa.com"
```

Also how can I find this items :

```
track0; (any track number);
track50 (any track number);
Track 0 (any track number);
Track 10 (any track number);
Track10 (any track number);
```

Comment: try searching the internet: regex lib

Comment: SO is full of regex questions. Why not search SO before posting another one?

Comment: Why not learn regular expressions? The ones you're asking for are fairly easy once you know how regular expressions work.

http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/1565922573

Comment: I found regex for number one (emails).
I need number two .

Comment: what exactly are you trying to match in the second one,
do you want the entire string track0; (any track number);
just track0;
or the track number between the brackets? i.e (any track number) 
without the brackets()???

Answer (score 1):

`\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`

found on http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Straight from Microsoft: [How to match a pattern by using regular expressions and Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308252)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
Regex emailregex = new Regex("(?<user>[^@]+)@(?<host>.+)");
Match m = emailregex.Match(s);
```

2) Do you want to validate all entries with that format or do you just want to get that "(any track number)" value?

Answer (score 0):

First one, try searching or use [Regular Expression Library](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email)

Second, try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\d]+\d");
```